# A question about the subspace $U_0$ of the dual space of $V$ for a vector subspace $U\subset V$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a vector subspace $U\subset V$ of a vector space $V$ set
$$
U_0= \{f\in V^* | \forall v\in U\colon f(v)=0 \}.
$$
Here $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$.

I want to show that if $v\in V$ is a vector with $f(v)=0$ for all $f\in U_0$, then $v\in U$. How to do that? It would be nice to have an elementary and direct proof without mentioning the bi-dual of $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_p)$ a basis of $U$ and we complete it on a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$ and let $(e_1^*,\ldots,e_n^*)$ its dual basis i.e.
$$e_i^*(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the standard Kronecker notation.

Now it's easy to see that 
$$U_0=\operatorname{span}(e_{p+1}^*,\ldots,e_n^*)$$

and if 
$$v=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k$$
such that
$$f(v)=0,\quad \forall f\in U_0$$
then by taking $f=e_k^*,\; k=p+1,\ldots,n$ we see that $x_k=0$ and then
$$v=\sum_{k=1}^p x_k e_k\in U$$